# Checking a checkbox by clicking its parent but not itself

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I've got checkboxes in li's. I've made it so clicking the li will toggle the checkbox but the trouble I've run into is clicking the checkbox itself will launch both a toggle on and toggle off.

Code:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]',this).each(function () { this.checked = !this.checked; });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattcoady/Vzqj3/

I want the checkbox to still function as it normally would. What can I do?

Comment: BlazeMonger's solution is better .. but an alternative using `event.target` http://jsfiddle.net/Vzqj3/2/

Comment: @isherwood did you look at the JSFiddle? If you click on the checkbox then nothing happens because it's checked but then the JS function attached to the `li` element's `click` event un-checks it.

Comment: Ah. I see it now. Friday brain. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop the propagation of the event. 
Add the click event for the checkbox which would stop event bubbling.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vzqj3/1/)

Answer (score 3):

No need for JavaScript here. Wrap the `label` around the entire contents of the list element, make it `display: block` (so it's full-width), and remove the JavaScript altogether.

CSS:

```
li label {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        The Checkbox
    </label></li>
     <li><label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        The Checkbox
    </label></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/XFgt4/

Comment: This is what I'd have done. That said, I still don't know what the problem was.

Comment: [Sushanth's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24088787/901048) will cover that. Basically, the click event on the checkbox bubbles up to the `li`, triggering another click that undoes the first. `e.stopPropagation()` prevents the bubbling.

Comment: This also meets basic accessibility requirements.

Comment: See also [this intro to event propagation/delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: Thanks but there's a lot more going where I need to keep the markup the way it was (I stripped the code down for the sake of the question).